# Is it possible to create a record type whose field is a function that takes a generic parameter, without specifying the type when creating the record?

Tags: f#

I want to define the following record type:

```
type LogFuncs = {
    LogWithLabel : string -> 'a -> unit
    LogWithLabelAndReturn : string -> 'a -> 'a }
```

The intention is that I can define one function of `string -> unit` and then use that to derive several convenience functions, like so:

```
let makeLogFuncs outputFunc =
    let logWithLabelFunc label value = sprintf "%s: %A" label value |> outputFunc
    let logWithLabelAndReturnFunc label value = logWithLabelFunc label value; value
    {   LogWithLabel = logWithLabelFunc
        LogWithLabelAndReturn = logWithLabelAndReturnFunc  }
```

But, the compiler won't let me do this without specifying an `<'a>` when making an instance of type LogFuncs, and that's not what I want to do -- I want to be able to call this function on *any* `'a`. (I will also want to provide related functions, hence the use of the record type.)

**Is it possible to define a record type with a field containing type parameter that is not also a type parameter of the record type itself?**

Comment: Where would you store the information on what `'a` acdtually is and how would you use it in a type safe way.  If you don't care about type safety just use object

Comment: I don't necessarily care about the type of 'a when I'm logging it, but when I'm logging it and then returning it, I want the return type to be exactly the same as the input type, not obj.

Comment: IMO interfaces (where you can do it) and object-expressions (to create such an interface) are a viable alternative to records here - some time ago [I blogged](http://gettingsharper.de/2014/09/29/church-numerals-net-and-working-around-the-value-restriction/#Interfaces_to_the_rescue) about something very similar - maybe you find it interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe it is possible to do with record types. But I can define a **class** which provides the mechanism I wanted:

```
type Logger (outputFunc: string->unit) =
    member __.LogWithLabel label value = sprintf "%s: %A" label value |> outputFunc
    member x.LogWithLabelAndReturn label value = x.LogWithLabel label value; value
```

Then I can do:

```
let log = new Loggery (printfn "%s")

let ``result should equal 5`` = 5 |> log.LogWithLabelAndReturn "Beans"
```

...and it correctly prints `"Beans: 5"` and returns `5`.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the record itself generic:

```
type LogFuncs<'a> = {
    LogWithLabel : string -> 'a -> unit
    LogWithLabelAndReturn : string -> 'a -> 'a }
```

That also makes the `makeLogFuncs` generic. It's still usable, but probably not in the way you want:

```
(makeLogFuncs (printfn "%s")).LogWithLabel "Number" 42
(makeLogFuncs (printfn "%s")).LogWithLabelAndReturn "Number" 42
(makeLogFuncs (printfn "%s")).LogWithLabel "Text" "Foo"
(makeLogFuncs (printfn "%s")).LogWithLabelAndReturn "Text" "Foo"
```

As the answer provided by *Overlord Zurg* implies, the OP approach is quite object-oriented, so use objects if you want to design the system in that way.